# Perform a Select on an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, observablecollection

In the same way I can filter items from my ObservableCollection using the Filter property on the collection's ICollectionView, is it possible to perform a Select on the collection too (In the same way I can with Linq)?

For an example, imagine I have a list of `Food` objects which doesn't have a `Selected` property, but I maintain which foods are selected in a separate list. Ideally I would want to perform my Select like so:

`view.Select(f => return new { Food = f, Selected = selectedFood.Contains(f)});`

I could then bind to the items returned from this Select like so:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FoodView}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Food.Name}"/>
        </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I'm currently achieving the result I want by maintaining separate ObservableCollections and updating them as needed, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you not make an object wrapper SelectableFood that has a Food and IsSelected property? Then you could use an ObservableCollection of that wrapper type instead of an observable collection of type Food.

Comment: Do you want to use the checkbox for interaction (read/write) or only presentation (readonly)

Comment: A generic SelectableItem<T> implementing INotifyPropertyChanged could help in general

Comment: @Lithium and Sir Rufo, I'm currently doing that, but the list needs to be displayed in multiple places, each with different selections made. I'm looking for something that will let me maintain one main list of items, then separate lists of what has been selected. Thanks for your fast responses, btw!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I created an `IMultiValueConverter` which takes two bindings, the first being the current Data Object and the second being the list of Selected Items:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FoodItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListExistsConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedFoodItems" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="50" Height="20"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Converter:

```
class ListExistsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null) return null;
        var item = values[0] as Food;
        var list = values[1] as List<Food>;

        return list.Contains(item);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

The resources used consist of an `ObservableCollection<Food> FoodItems` and a `List<Food> SelectedFoodItems`. Perhaps not the most elegant but should be easy to switch between SelectedItem lists as needed.